# Invisible symbol in matplotlib text

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, text

I'm looking for a way to put an invisible symbol (or whitespace) at the end of the string passed to matplotlib text, i.e.

```
ax.text(1.0, 1.0, 'xxx: ')
```

but, apparently matplotlib automatically strip all the strings. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use `ax.text(1.0, 1.0, 'xxx:   ', bbox=dict(fc='r'))` to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like matplotlib does not strip text string.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.text(1, 1, 'xxx:       ', ha='right')
```

[image]

Comment: if you add ha='right' in text options, than it become attached to the colon, but not to whitespace

Comment: Nope, whitespace is still in place (I added a few of them for clear picture). See updated code above

Comment: Ok, I found a problem. This is because I have text.usetex: True option in matplotlibrc file...

Comment: So with "text.usetext: True" option, I still can not find a solution for invisible symbol (or margin equal to the one symbol width)